# How to make an optional scrollbar?

Tags: python, import, tkinter, scrollbar

The following code is meant to: ask the use to import a text file, store the lines of the file in a list then display that list on a label. My problem is when the user tries to import a text file which is really long. Right now, not all the text will be displayed if it is a long file. I'd like to know how to have a scrollbar/scrolling frame appear once the length of the file reaches a certain length.

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

window = tkinter.Tk()

def import_txt():
    global import_list
    file_name = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")]) 
    import_list = []

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        go.pack()
        import_list = f.readlines()
    f.close()

def display():
    global import_list
    display_txt.config(text=str(import_list))
    display_txt.pack()

start = tkinter.Button(window, text="Import", command=import_txt)
start.pack()
go = tkinter.Button(window, text="GO", command=display)
display_txt = tkinter.Label(window)

window.mainloop()
import tkinter 
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

window = tkinter.Tk()

def import_txt():
    global import_list
    file_name = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")]) 
    import_list = []

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        go.pack()
        import_list = f.readlines()
    f.close()

def display():
    global import_list
    display_txt.config(text=str(import_list))
    display_txt.pack()

start = tkinter.Button(window, text="Import", command=import_txt)
start.pack()
go = tkinter.Button(window, text="GO", command=display)
display_txt = tkinter.Label(window)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a reason to not just have the scrollbar always be there?

Comment: In the event where the text file isn't big enough. And just because I want there to be less on my GUI when not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [scrolledtext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html) widget instead of a label.  Is there some special consideration why this won't work for you?  You can configure it so the user can't modify the text, if that's the issue.  Just configure it with `state=tk.DISABLED`

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution from [PurityLake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2133491/puritylake): https://stackoverflow.com/a/15227842/709998

I think you might be able to at least modify it if your requirements are slightly different.

Comment: That's not my solution.

Comment: Well I guess I can't read properly!  I had it bookmarked with a collection of other tricks and the folder is just named Bryan Oakley tkinter.  Thanks for pointing that out.